# What if need to to sort grouped data on a server?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDb 2.0, c# driver 1.6rc: Is there any way to sort results of data aggregations (group or map-reduce) on a server side? Lets say as a result of grouping we have many thousands of records which would be much faster to sort on a server side. All I found on the official MongoDb web site is this comment: "*To order the grouped data, simply sort it client-side upon return.*" ([Aggregation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation)). Does it mean server sorting is not supported for such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of group() are returned as single BSON object, so sorting must take place client-side.  The output of map reduce, on the other hand, can be placed into a collection, which you can subsequently query and sort server-side.

Output options for MR:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions